# Other applications of Karger-Stein branching amplification?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, randomized-algorithms, teaching

I just taught the [Karger-Stein randomized mincut algorithm](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=234534) in my graduate algorithms class.  This is a real [algorithmic gem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/189/algorithms-from-the-book), so I can't *not* teach it, but it always leaves me frustrated, because I don't know  any other applications of the main technique.  (So it's hard to assign homework that drives the point home.)

Karger and Stein's algorithm is a refinement of an earlier algorithm of Karger, which iteratively contracts random edges until the graph has only two vertices; this simple algorithm runs in $O(n^2)$ time and returns a minimum cut with probability $\Omega(1/n^2)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the input graph.  The refined "Recursive Contraction Algorithm" iteratively contracts random edges until the number of vertices drops from $n$ to $n/\sqrt{2}$, recursively calls itself *twice* on the remaining graph, and returns the smaller of the two resulting cuts.  A straightforward implementation of the refined algorithm runs in $O(n^2\log n)$ time and returns a minimum cut with probability $\Omega(1/\log n)$.  (There are more efficient implementations of these algorithms, and better randomized algorithms.)

What other randomized algorithms use similar branching amplification techniques?  I'm especially interested in examples that *don't* (obviously) involve graph cuts.

Comment: Nice question, Jeff !

Comment: Is that a tumbleweed?

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: also, what would you consider an example of branching amplification ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumbleweed#Symbolism

Comment: tumbleweed is also a badge on this site, which certainly doesn't apply to your question, @JeffE!

Comment: @Suresh: Sorry if my terminology is unclear.  The point of the Karger-Stein *branching* algorithm (reduce and recurse twice) is to *amplify* the probability of success from $1/n^2$ to $1/\log n$ without running a quadratic number of independent trials.  Hence "branching amplification".

Comment: a thought: while the connection is tenuous, Raz's parallel repetition theorem has the same effect (of exponentially increasing the success rate using parallel "rounds"). It'll take a lot more reading before I can figure if there's a real connection

Answer (score 5):

@JeffE,  Here is a paper that [counts min weight cycles](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190%2894%2900202-A) in a graph. As far as I remember, it was definitely inspired by Karger's technique/result and it was a fun proof.  Hope this helps with the teaching.

Comment: This paper does not count the number of minimum weight cycles in a graph.  Instead, it gives a bound on the number of cycles whose weight is at most some constant multiple of the weight of the minimum weight cycle.