# New proofs from "The Book"

Tags: big-list, proofs

The book ["Proofs from The Book"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK), referencing Erdős' notion of God's book, which contains the most beautiful proofs, was published in 1998.

> Are there any new proofs that should be considered for "The Book"?

While this is somewhat opinion-based, I think the voting platform in our community is an excellent way to rank the beauty of proofs.

Comment: related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/189/

Comment: Each new edition has new theorems, the latest is from 2009, so new proofs are considered.

Comment: Also, I think that this question is much more appropriate for mathoverflow.net.

Comment: @domotorp - you're welcome to flag the question for moderator attention, they can decide if they want to move it or close it. I still recon there may be some value in having it online, since it is possible to get some interesting answers that are not in the book.

Comment: But why here and not on mathoverflow?

Comment: As I said - if the moderators choose to move it - so be it. This site is more  exclusive to experts than mathoverflow, in my opinion, so I put it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is much more appropriate for mathoverflow.

Comment: @Shaull, you are thinking of math.stackexchange rather than mathoverflow.net, which is a site for professional mathematicians.

Comment: related: [An example of a beautiful proof that would be accessible at the high school level?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/74841/)